# What does UpdateTip mean?

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization

Example the debug log:

`2014-06-27 12:59:10 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002a03b175f183c3bbc440f5c2a171e958bfd504582f711f70  height=308004  log2_work=79.405055  tx=41447698  date=2014-06-27 00:04:17 progress=0.998105`

There could be dozens of those.

Whatever bitcoin is doing with this 'UpdateTip', it seems very CPU consuming. So what is going on, and is there any way to skip this/make it less CPU intense?

Comment: I looked up `log2_work` inside main.cpp and I can't follow its calculation by `log(chainActive.Tip()->nChainWork.getdouble())/log(2.0)`..What is `->` explicitely indicating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an earlier Version of bitcoin-qt the line was the following:

> SetBestChain: new best=0000000000000419f719  height=212580  work=666804971104474944731

From: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=136628.0

> In the log messages, new best is the start of the hash of the block
>   that it considers to be the head of the best chain, height is the
>   length of the path through the tree, and work is the sum of the work
>   embedded in that path.

It basically means that your client received a new best blockchain, so a new block was found. You can compare those log entries, they will allways increase in height and its always followed by `ProcessBlock: ACCEPTED`

I'm not sure why this is CPU intense for you, i didn't recognized this at my client yet. There is no way to remove this function because its a fundamental one of bitcoin-qt client and the bitcoin protocol. Also making it less CPU intense can only be done by changing the source of the client.